Building ffmpeg to support g722.1 audio format
Due to usage scenarios, I now want to give ffmpeg version 4.4.1 support for the g722.1 audio format。I learned about polycom's royalty-free license for g722.1 and am now applying for the license.
I also found a libg7221 library on github (https://github.com/Lastique/libg7221) and I added the project of this library to shift media project (shift media project can be debugged using visual studio) ffmpeg source code).
I added the codec id of g722.1 in the enum AVCodecID, and created a new g722_1.c in the libcodec directory, the code is as follows, now it compiles successfully.
Now start ffplay in shift media project to play the video file with audio format g722.1, it can recognize the audio of g722.1 format, but there is no sound in the playback, look at the sdl_audio_callback and audio_thread in ffplay are executing normally.
In the g722_1.c file, in the call to g722.1 decode function g722_1_decode, the pre-decoded g722.1 format audio is written to the audio.srn file, and the decoded PCM format audio is written to the audio.wav file.
audio.srn use polycom sirenZip.exe to decode or play (sirenZip.exe play g722.1 format audio, it will first convert the g722.1 format audio to wav format before playing), are normal.
When I play the audio.wav file using VLC and other players, the sound is not right. When I use audacity to open the audio.wav to view waveforms, only a very small amount of waveforms are seen.
Now the problem should be in the libg7221 library to convert g722.1 format audio to PCM here, but I can't continue to investigate, because I'm not familiar with the algorithms and principles of g722.1, and there is no audio player on the network to get the parameters of the g722.1 format!
Can someone please help me to see or point out how I can continue to troubleshoot, thank you very much!

#include "avcodec.h"
#include "codec_internal.h"
#include "decode.h"
#include "encode.h"
#include "libg722_1/g722_1.h"

typedef struct G722_1_Context {
    AVClass *class;

    g722_1_decode_state_t* s;
    FILE* g7221file;
    FILE* wavfile;
} G722_1_Context;

static const AVClass g722_1_decoder_class = {
    .class_name = "G.722.1 decoder",
    .item_name  = av_default_item_name,
    .option     = options,
    .version    = LIBAVUTIL_VERSION_INT,
};

static av_cold int g722_1_decode_initi(AVCodecContext *avctx)
{
    G722_1_Context* c = avctx->priv_data;
    if (avctx->ch_layout.nb_channels > 1){
        avpriv_request_sample(avctx, "Decoding more than one channel");
        return AVERROR_PATCHWELCOME;
    }

    av_channel_layout_uninit(&avctx->ch_layout);
    avctx->ch_layout = (AVChannelLayout)AV_CHANNEL_LAYOUT_MONO;
    avctx->sample_fmt = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16;

    if ((c->s = g722_1_decode_init(NULL, avctx->bit_rate, avctx->sample_rate)) == NULL) {
        av_log(avctx, AV_LOG_ERROR, "g722_1_decode_init failed\n");
        return AVERROR(EINVAL);
    }

    c->g7221file = fopen("audio.srn", "wb");
    c->wavfile = fopen("audio.wav", "wb");
    return 0;
}

static int g722_1_decode_frame(AVCodecContext *avctx, AVFrame *frame,
                             int *got_frame_ptr, AVPacket *avpkt)
{
    G722_1_Context* c = avctx->priv_data;
    const uint8_t *buf = avpkt->data;
    int buf_size = avpkt->size;
    int16_t *samples;
    int out_samples, ret;

    fwrite(buf, sizeof(uint8_t), avpkt->size, c->g7221file);
    fflush(c->g7221file);

    out_samples = buf_size * 8 / (1.0 * 16000 / (16000 * 1)) * 2;

    /* get output buffer */
    frame->nb_samples = out_samples;
    if ((ret = ff_get_buffer(avctx, frame, 0)) < 0)
        return ret;

    samples = (int16_t *)frame->data[0];
    frame->nb_samples = g722_1_decode(c->s, samples, buf, buf_size);
    fwrite(samples, sizeof(int16_t), frame->nb_samples, c->wavfile);
    fflush(c->wavfile);

    *got_frame_ptr = 1;
    return buf_size;
}

static void g722_1_decode_close(AVCodecContext* avctx)
{
    G722_1_Context* c = avctx->priv_data;
    fclose(c->g7221file);
    fclose(c->wavfile);
    g722_1_decode_release(c->s);
}

const FFCodec ff_g722_1_decoder = {
    .p.name         = "g722_1",
    CODEC_LONG_NAME("G.722_1"),
    .p.type         = AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO,
    .p.id           = AV_CODEC_ID_G722_1,
    .priv_data_size = sizeof(G722_1_Context),
    .init           = g722_1_decode_initi,
    FF_CODEC_DECODE_CB(g722_1_decode_frame),
    .close          = g722_1_decode_close,
    .p.capabilities = AV_CODEC_CAP_DR1 | AV_CODEC_CAP_CHANNEL_CONF,
    .p.priv_class   = &g722_1_decoder_class,
};


Why don't you at least post the output of ffprobe for the file? Apparently G.722.1 is essentially (a subset of) Siren(7), for which ffmpeg has builtin decoder. However, as I can see here, the wav/riff demuxer only have (some?) support for a "MSN variant". You may also try to force the decoder to work in the "normal" mode by specifying -c:a siren before -i.

Here's what I did: . \ffprobed.exe -i C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\h264+g722_20240826143257.mp4 printout:
Duration: 00:05:44.57, start: 365.871489, bitrate: 3020 kb/s
Stream #0:0[0x1e0]: Video: h264 (High), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 729:728 DAR 162:91], 30 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn
Stream #0:1[0x1c0]: Audio: g722_1, 16000 Hz, mono, s16, 16 kb/s

Actually, what I meant was ffprobe in a "vanilla" ffmpeg. Besides, since apparently you are talking about a g772.1 stream in an mp4 file, what exact changes did you make to the corresponding demuxer code? Have you tried making the demuxer use the siren decoder instead of this wrapper+library you were trying?

Yes, before this, I learned on the Internet that ffmpeg has integrated the siren decoder. In the ffplay command, the audio is forced to use -acodec siren, which is also an error. There is no sound.
The siren decoder is a variant of the Siren decoder modified by Microsoft. The following URL describes the differences between the Siren decoder and the g722.1 decoder
https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php/Siren
